# set maximum to extjs guage chart from .net web service

Tags: c#, extjs, charts

i've got a guage chart in extjs using MVC approach and a web method in C# which I use to get data for the chart. Code I got from C# web method is

```
<root>
  <record>
    <count>10</count>
    <total>20</total>
  </record>
</root>
```

In a gauge chart I can easily show a value (count) but maximum value in my case must depend on total field from the xml.

I've got a store

```
Ext.define('mystore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'myModel',
    autoLoad: true,
    storeId: 'storeId',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'url to.asmx/method',
        reader: {
            type: 'xml',
            root: 'root',
            record: 'record'
        }
    }
});
```

and a view

```
Ext.define('myview' ,{
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'myview',
    initComponent: function()
var store1 = Ext.create('mystore');
Ext.apply(this, {
            layout: 'vbox',
            height:300,           

            items: [{...
},{                    
                    width:'50%',
                    height:200,
                    xtype: 'chart',

                    style: 'background:#FFFFFF',
                    animate: {
                        easing: 'bounceOut',
                        duration: 500
                    },

                    store: store1,
                    insetPadding: 25,
                    flex: 1,
                    axes: [{
                        type: 'gauge',
                        position: 'gauge',
                        minimum: 0,
                        maximum: 100, //here instead of 100 I need to get a value from //xml from web method. So here I need to get total
                        steps: 10,
                        margin: 7
                    }],
                    series: [{
                        type: 'gauge',
                        field: 'count',
                        donut: 60,
                        colorSet: ['#3AA8CB', '#DDDDDD']
                    }]
                }]
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how you are getting the data from the xml into the chart?

Comment: I user MVC model and load xml via a store.Ext.define('myStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',                                     proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'url to asmx/web_method',
        extraParams: {
            type:'p_ready'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'xml',
            root: 'root',
            record:'record'
        }
    }

Comment: What does `store.getProxy().getReader().rawData` contain?

Comment: <root>
  <record>
    <count>10</count>
    <total>20</total>
  </record>
</root>

Comment: So now you have the data (`store.getProxy().getReader().rawData`), and you know where to put it (`gauge.axes[0].maximum`), right?

Comment: I didn't understand you correctly Alexander. It's what it should be. In my case alert(store.getProxy().getReader().rawData) shows "undefined". Does it mean that I can't get needed data anywhere outside gauge block? Cuz the edited code above works as long as I don't start using store1 anywhere else outside the chart

Comment: If rawData is `undefined`, it is impossible that there is any record in the store.

Comment: indeed there is one. Alexander, could you please tell me if it works like this: first a chart in view is fully initialized and then data from stores are loaded. If it's true then it's logic why I get my store is undefined but works when the page is loaded.

Comment: Everything you want to do with `store.getProxy().getReader().rawData` may only happen after store is loaded, for example `store.on('load',function() { HERE });`

Comment: I managed to get the number I tried to get using store.on('load',function(). But how to set gauge.axes[0].maximum? I've got a gouge id like gouge1 and try to use Ext.getCmp('gauge1') to set maximum. var g = Ext.getCmp('gauge1'); g.axes[0].maximum = 3; or g.axes[0].setValue('maximum',val); but nothing works

Comment: Thanks Alexander. Your answers and responses helped a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to set maximum dynamically by creating an object of a store:

```
var store1 = Ext.create('app.store.MyStore');
```

then use a store load:

```
store1.load({
        callback: function(records, operation, success) {            
            var g = Ext.getCmp('my gauge id');
            g.axes.getAt(0).maximum = records[0].data.a field from C# query put into xml;
        }
    });
```

***Thanks Alexander for his answers and reposes in comments.***